# Objective-C Copying a view

Tags: objective-c, view, copy, subview

So I've got a quick question here...

I've got an instance of a view controller object, lets call it `viewCon1`, and it has several subview's placed on it each with unique properties. Lets call them `sub1`, `sub2`, and `sub3`. Now, I add each of these subviews programatically doing something to the extent of:

```
//create the subviews
TaskUIButton *sub1 = [[TaskUIButton alloc] init];
TaskUIButton *sub2 = [[TaskUIButton alloc] init];
TaskUIButton *sub3 = [[TaskUIButton alloc] init];

//add them to viewCon1
[viewCon1.view addSubView:sub1];
[viewCon1.view addSubView:sub2];
[viewCon1.view addSubView:sub3];
```

Now here is where I don't know how to proceed. I need to create another view controller object called `viewCon2` and make it exactly like `viewCon1` with identical (albiet separate) subviews attached to it. So for instance, lets say that `viewCon1`'s `sub1` had a title of `"foo"`, I need `viewCon2` to also have an identical subview with a title of `"foo"`, etc.

Is there any easy way to go about this?

I'd appreciate any insight, thanks!

Comment: Create a `UIViewController` subclass and add the buttons inside it. It will automatically be available in all instances of that subclass.

Comment: You say that you are already working with an instance of a view controller object - so surely you can just create another instance of the same class to solve your issue?

Comment: well, the number of button subviews isnt known at compilation. The button subviews are added by the user, and upon the users request, another viewcontroller (`viewCon2`) is created. Creating an instance of my view controller object will just give me a blank slate with no button subviews.

Comment: The problem here is that the views have properties which are needed in two locations (and you can't have a view in two places at once). You can either separate the properties you need away from the views and let them share those properties somewhere else or do something like a "copy" method where you just copy all properties you need from one to another and call it for each view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither UIViewController nor UIView implements the NSCopying protocol, so duplicating such objects is more than a one-step process. The general idea is to create a new instance of the class in question and copy the original object's configuration.

Since you already have code that configures the views for your view controller, the easiest thing will be to call that method again to create a second instance of the view controller. I realize that your code may not be set up to do that right now, so you may need to refactor to make that possible.

Based on your comments above, it sounds like you may be storing some state in your view rather than letting the view reflect the data stored in your application. It may help to determine what information is determining the layout of your view and make sure that data is properly represented in your app's data model. If you can do that, you should be able to simply create a new view controller based on the same data and get an identical layout.

Comment: That's unfortunate that the NSCopying protocol isn't implemented. I think the easiest way to go about copying the view with my current datamodel is to do what vakio suggested and make a copy method that just copies each property for each button subview. A bit tedious, but it'll work.

Comment: You can probably see why NSCopying isn't implemented -- a single view may contain many other views, some of which may not be copyable. Since you know what you want copied from each view, though, you could add a category to each of your view classes that adopts NSCopying. That'd be a clean, consistent way to implement your copying method.

Comment: Awesome, I'll see what I can do. Thanks!